# Azure App Service keeping old files at /home/site/wwwroot/

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, kudu

I'm deploying nodejs application to Azure App Service with visual studio code extension (Deploy to web app). However when I inspect the files section, I found some old file/ files from previous deployment are still exist at /home/site/wwwroot/ folder.

For example first deployment have `A.js`, and second deployment I renamed it to `B.js`, /home/site/wwwroot/ will endup with `A.js` and `B.js`.

How can I resolved this issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Check the settings for that VSCode extension, there should be a flag to clear out the filesystem in the destination before deployment. In Azure CLI you would pass `--clean` to `az webapp deploy ...`

Comment: Hi @evilSnobu and thanks for the reply. I couldn't find the flag settings at vscode, could you give me more hit about it? Thanks.

Comment: Can't find the setting in the extension. Try opening an issue here - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureappservice/issues. Meanwhile you could use Azure CLI to deploy with the `--clean` flag.

Answer (score 0):

on publish page click on show all settings.

[image]

Make sure Remove additional files at destination.

[image]

Before check **Remove additional files at destination**. showing old file on wwwroot folder.

[image]

[image]

After check **Remove additional files at destination**. showing old file on wwwroot folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is this publish page? Having trouble finding it.